# Google Cloud IAM Role to only start/stop instances?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, access-control

In Google Cloud IAM, there doesn't seem to be a role that is restricted down to only being able to stop/start existing instances.

Is it possible to scope permissions down so a given user can only start/stop existing instances?

Answer (score 2):

I am attempting to do the same thing two years after the question was posted ( 2019-Jul-03 ), and this is still not possible, so the answer is still 'No', this is not possible.

The one answer that was provided does not provide any direct information as to how to meet this requirement of granting access to allow just these two activities (start/stop a GCE VM/instance ), and nothing more.

It leads you to believe that it does, but it does not provide any direct or useful information on how to do this, and therefore is misleading.

It says you 'should' be able to do this, but provides no information as to why custom roles should allow you to do this.

Had the user gone and actually tried to do this, he would have found that it is not possible, and would have answered: 'No', this is not possible, at this time.

There are no granular permissions available, that you could add to a custom role to achieve this.  The one response has no useful function except for misdirection.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently via the predefined roles.

However, with [Custom Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) (currently in Alpha) you should be able to do this:

> Currently, Google Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM) provides
>   predefined roles that give granular access to specific Google Cloud
>   Platform resources and prevent unwanted access to other resources.
>
> IAM now provides the ability to create customized Cloud IAM roles.
>   With this release, you can create a custom IAM role with one or more
>   permissions and grant a custom role to users who are part of your
>   organization. Cloud IAM provides a UI and API for creating and
>   managing custom roles.